# Is there any way to change the default startup text in vim?

Tags: default-settings

When you first open vim there is a text that says "VIM - Vi IMproved version......"
Is there a file or setting you can use to change this default text? I've looked on the internet and here and couldn't find anything mentioning it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negative

...unless you compile Vim yourself, that is.

The version numbers are in src/version.h. Excerpts ...

```
#define VIM_VERSION_MAJOR       8
#define VIM_VERSION_MINOR       2
```

```
#define VIM_VERSION_SHORT     VIM_VERSION_MAJOR_STR "." VIM_VERSION_MINOR_STR
#define VIM_VERSION_MEDIUM    VIM_VERSION_SHORT
#define VIM_VERSION_LONG_ONLY "VIM - Vi IMproved " VIM_VERSION_MEDIUM
```

The rest of the text is in `intro_message()` in src/version.c where everything is assembled.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you mean text displayed by `:h :intro` command. No, you cannot change it, but you can fill the first empty buffer with arbitrary text instead. Intro screen won't be shown in this case.

That "welcome" buffer can provide some extra functionality using custom syntax, keymappings and so on. There are plenty of such plugins out there.